# Firestore offline seems not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am react-native and rnfirebase.io to connect to firestore
My environment is below:

```
Environment:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1
  Node: 8.9.2
  Yarn: 1.5.1
  npm: 5.8.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
  Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4720617

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
  react-native: 0.55.2 => 0.55.2
```

I want my app to work offline and I saw that Firestore support offline by default at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline.

Below are my code to add a row to Firestore

```
const db = firebase.firestore().collection('bill');

const data = {
  userid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
  year: year,
  month: month,
  description: description,
  dateCreated: new Date()
};

db.add(data).then(ref => {
   console.log('Added bill with ID: ', ref.id);
}).catch(error => {
   console.error("Error adding bill: ", error);     
});
```

When there is internet connection then everything goes smoothly. When I turn off internet connection and tried to add a record, it is like taking forever to add.

I authenticate my user anonymously like below

```
  componentWillMount() {

    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (!user) {

      firebase.auth()
        .signInAnonymouslyAndRetrieveData()
        .then(credential => {
          if (credential) {
            console.log('default app user ->', credential.user.toJSON());
          } else {
            console.log('failed to auth anonymous user');
          }
      });

    }    

  }
```